# Double Record on itab

Tags: abap

I have problem,
I have 1 itab like this

```
  Do.No.    Material     Amount
  10001      AAA           25000
  10001      AAA           25000
  10002      AAA           25000
```

My quest is How I can Replace Second record (10001)  with third record (10002).

Thank For you Help

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES`.](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPDELETE_DUPLICATES.htm)